# How to use defer and make JS plugin working as well

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

When I use defer on app.js, there is a js plugin not working properly.

If I remove defer, although the plugin works, but there is a warning to ask me to use defer, and I don't know what to do.

```js
// resource/js/app.js
require('./bootstrap');

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

import mask from '@alpinejs/mask'
Alpine.plugin(mask);

window.Alpine = Alpine;
Alpine.start();
```

```js
// webpack.mix.js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]);
```

This is  the test.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <livewire:styles />
    <livewire:scripts />    
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"  defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input x-mask="99/99/9999" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
</body>
</html>
```

If I use `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"  defer></script>`, then the `x-mask` plugin will not working.

If I remove defer and use `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>`, the `x-mask` works, but there is a warning `Alpine Warning: Unable to initialize. Trying to load Alpine before` `is available. Did you forget to add`defer`in Alpine's` `tag?` on the chrome browser console.

What should I do? Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Did you put an `x-data` directive to a parent element?

Comment: no, I'didn't. Even when I removed defer and worked, still didn't. I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dauros, it works after I put an `x-data` directive to a parent element. (I also put the `defer` to the app.js)

```html
<div x-data="{ date: '' }">
    <input x-mask="99/99/9999" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" x-model="date">
</div>
```

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

It doesn't mention on [the alpineJS x-mask plugin page](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/mask).

And I finally understand what the document said about the `x-data` in the [Start Here](https://alpinejs.dev/start-here) and [x-data](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data).

> Everything in Alpine starts with the x-data directive.

> Everything in Alpine starts with an x-data directive. Inside of x-data, in plain JavaScript, you declare an object of data that Alpine will track.

Answer (score 0):

@dauros hit the nail on the head as I struggled with this for a bit before I realized that the main alpine.js website did indeed seem to omit the x-data in the parent element!

Comment: Show us some code that resolves the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).